# Is there a general formula for antiderivatives the same way there is for derivatives?

Tags: integration

So, I know that first-order derivatives can be calculated with the formula:
$$
f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}
$$
Is there such a limit/standard form for antiderivatives?

Comment: The HENSTOCK integral gives such a limit

Comment: A minor typo in the title: "an antiderivative(s)".

Comment: Thank you both, noted.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you, it does answer my question, although I already marked it as answered (or tried to). Very useful insight, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such a limit expression for antiderivatives directly, mainly because antiderivatives of a function are not unique, and how varied the family of antiderivatives also depends on the connectedness of the domain of the function.

The fundamental theorem of calculus does state that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $$\int_a^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ is an antiderivative of $f$, and this does have a limit definition. However, this only works in some circumstances, since it relies on the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a formula to obtain elementary functions, then the answer is no, there isn't.

If you have an elementary function, its derivative is also an elementary function. This is however not true if you go the other way. There are even many relatively simple such functions, for example $e^{x^2}$ and $\sin(x)/x$.

If you are not looking for elementary functions, then for any continuous function $f$, the function $g$ given by $$g(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$$ is an anti derivative. Here we choose $a$ and $x$ so that the integral is inside the functions domain.

Comment: @Math What do you mean I forgot the $-g(a)$ term? That is my definition of $g$.

Comment: Oops! I misread . Sorry but this  doesn't answer the question sice it only works for  derivatives which are  continuous functions ;you may want to see my comment